# Why does the minor upgrade of our product created using InstallShield fail to install on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, installshield

The minor upgrade for our product created with InstallShield 2008 installs on Win XP perfectly, but fails on Windows 7 32 bit and 64 bit. It prompts for the admin privilege and after that, although it appears like it has finished installing (it even says "Installation finished successfully"), the old DLLs are not replaced.

There are about 15 DLLs that must have new product code.

I am completely at sea here. I have no previous experience with InstallShield but am assigned this job due to resource constraints at our company.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got that wrong. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Did you update the resources in the InstallShield project?

Comment: No should I? I inherited the project file and I simply built it. It works on XP as I said. Does Windows 7 need rebuilding or something?

Comment: Have you logged the installer?

Answer (score 0):

Open the ISM InstallShield project file in InstallShield 2008 then goto Installation Designer. Check beneath Application Data section that files, folders, components etc are valid for the Windows 7 environment.

Often the issues with early MSI's intended for Windows Installer 2.0 (eg WinXP) require's either repacking or enhancements. For DLL's, right click on the file in InstallShield and select properties. Ensure DLL's self register, you can also set permissions (as well for select groups/users based on your AD config).

Also, try generating a verbose, detail MSI log via a DOS command prompt execution:

1. Installing 'setup.exe' CMD:  setup.exe /v /qn /l*v "%temp%\setup.log"
2. Installing 'setup.msi' CMD:  msiexec /i setup.msi /qn /l*v "%temp%\setup.log"

Note: Search the installation log file searching for string instances of 'return value 3' (generic error) or 'error' and try pinpoint where the installer is failing.